# What is the recommended way to use VeraCrypt in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, encryption, veracrypt

I have a number of encrypted volumes on external media encrypted either with TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt. What is the recommended way to install and use VeraCrypt under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I chose to download [veracrypt-1.21-setup.tar.bz2](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html), uncompress it and install manually:

- Download the latest release (from link above):

  ```
  wget https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.23/+download/veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2
  ```
- Unpack it:

  ```
  $ tar xvf veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2 
  veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x64  
  veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x86
  veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64
  veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x86
  ```
- Run your installer of choice:

  ```
  ./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64`
  ```
- Done! Run veracrypt with

  ```
  vercrypt
  ```

I chose not to follow [s3m3n's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/937325/527764) because I would prefer not to have encryption automatically updated so as not to lose access to encrypted containers in case of some incompatibility between versions.

VeraCrypt is mature and stable, and occasional manual updates can easily be handled.

Comment: «I would not like to have encryption automatically updated not to loose access to encrypted containers in case some incompatibility between versions.»

One downside is that one needs to regularly check if there is an update that fixes security flaws

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the process you describe does not check signatures or checksums?

Comment: Thanks for valuable comment. You're more than welcome to enhance my answer.

Comment: `wget https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.25.4/+download/veracrypt-console-1.25.4-Ubuntu-20.04-amd64.deb && dpkg -i veracrypt-console-1.25.4-Ubuntu-20.04-amd64.deb`

Comment: For GUI: `wget https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.25.9/+download/veracrypt-1.25.9-Ubuntu-20.04-amd64.deb && dpkg -i veracrypt-1.25.9-Ubuntu-20.04-amd64.deb && apt --fix-broken install`.. apt fix adds two packages at 22MB.

Answer (score 37):

There is user **Unit 193** who prepares ready builds of VeraCrypt on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/encryption). You can easily install it by adding his repo to Ubuntu sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption
sudo apt update
sudo apt install veracrypt
```

*You should be aware that this repo is not related to the software developer and because of it you can't be 100% sure what you install or update in future. However Unit 193 is [Xubuntu developer and he is well known in open source community](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unit193). This is enough for me to sleep well.*

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your valuable answer, but I've chosen another path and did not test whether this repo actually works. Anyway thanks for knowledgable contribution.

Comment: I'm going to comment on this because it still applies to current versions. I think it's important to keep in mind that using a repository not related to the project in a security package as this, might not be the best idea. You should check thoroughly who is the owner before adding any repository, but this is specially important if the package will be handling confidential information.

Comment: @Leo I added proper notice for all ppl installing from this repo.

Comment: For your info: I've just used this method in Ubuntu 18.04 (Pop_OS) and it works. The repo contains 18.04 binaries.

Comment: @pawel-debski so you actually changed your mind and used my method? Cool.

Comment: This time I decided to venture on the other path that leads through the shadows on unknown :-)

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption && sudo apt update && sudo apt install veracrypt`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't trust the PPA or prefer to install it yourself, you can follow this:

Read https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Digital%20Signatures.html & download the `tar.bz2` files.

Download the key with ID shown in the above webpage: 5069A233D55A0EEB174A5FC3821ACD02680D16DE

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 5069A233D55A0EEB174A5FC3821ACD02680D16DE
```

Verify files (replace ## with the version of your installation):

```
gpg --verify veracrypt-1.##-sha256sum.txt.sig veracrypt-1.##-sha256sum.txt
gpg --verify veracrypt-1.##-setup.tar.bz2.sig veracrypt-1.##-setup.tar.bz2
```

Install files:

```
tar xvjf veracrypt-1.##-setup.tar.bz2
./veracrypt-1.##-setup-gui-x64
```

Done. You should have a GUI app in your desktop.

*Note that if you don't have a trust chain to the PGP key, you only trust the key because the website says it's theirs, and so you trust the website hasn't been hacked, or the key compromised another way.*

Comment: Note that the key has changed since then: https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/fcd0da57/

Answer (score 2):

All of the other answers rely on trusting somebody to compile VeraCrypt for you, with no possibility to check whether or not the executable has been tampered with.

## Trust, but verify

To remedy this situation, I created a Dockerfile called [docker-build-veracrypt](https://github.com/maresb/docker-build-veracrypt) which generates a reproducible build of the VeraCrypt executable, directly from the publicly available source code of VeraCrypt and wxWidgets on GitHub.  You have the following options:

- You can simply download the resulting executable.
- You can download an image from Docker Hub containing the executable as the result of an automated build of my Dockerfile.
- You can build the Dockerfile yourself, and producing the executable on your own hardware.
- Reading my Dockerfile and performing similar commands, you can build the executable on your host system.

Moreover, I have provided checksums (MD5, SHA256 and BLAKE2) which you can use to verify that the results of the above four procedures agree.  Thus it is easy for anyone to audit my build process.