# How can I install VeraCrypt on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, encryption

I've downloaded a `tar.bz2` file which I'm having problems with.

There's no PPA as far as I can tell.

I'm using a 64-bit machine.

Steagee basically gave commands which are similar if not the same as ones I've tried which also made terminal say [image: this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to use VeraCrypt in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929195/recommended-way-to-use-veracrypt-in-ubuntu)

Comment: That doesn't work for me because I can't get terminal to select a file. I know the cd thing for directory but right now, terminal is telling me no such file...

Comment: That's usually because there is no such file. Use `ls` to see what is in the current working directory, `cd <directory-name>` to enter a directory, and `cd ..` to move to back up to the parent directory.

Comment: If you're having problems with the downloaded installer, it might help to explain the problem you're encountering.  As this stands, it is exceptionally vague about what exactly the problems you're encountering are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack the archive:

```
tar jxf veracrypt-1.23-setup.tar.bz2
```

Run the installation:

```
./veracrypt-1.23-setup-gui-x64
```

Comment: This worked when I followed @Zanna s advice. First I did cd <directory-name> then I input ls. After that the above 2 commands worked.

Comment: The unpack part I did in the file managers GUI but the 4 files it unpacks were in a folder whereas the unpack command put the 4 directly into the directory.